# In Protobuf-net, is it possible to serialize non-decorated classes?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

To Serialize a class with protobuf-net, you neet to provide the class and property attributes [ProtoContract] and [ProtoMember(n)]  -- where n is 1,2,3,..,etc

Appart from cloning to a mirror image of a class, is it possible to serialize/deserialize a class we don't have control over?

For example:

using ProtoBuf;

- Serializer.Serialize<Exception>(OutputStream, exception);

or

- Serializer.Serialize<Tuple<Data,Exception>>(OutputStream, dataWithPossibleException);

NB. say Data has [ProtoContract] / [ProtoMember] and the others do not.

possible approaches:

- It would be nice if we had "extension attributes" that worked like extension methods.  [not possible]
- replicate the class locally and then copy to / from the object before serializing / deserializing  [that would work, but productivity goes down]
- generate an external proto file/definition for the class and store this in resources?  [anyone know how to go about this?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are options in v2 here:

- you can configure a RuntimeTypeModel telling it about types and members without needing any attributes
- for types that are awkward, a surrogate can be supplied to make serialization easier (it must have conversion operators to/from the original type)
- for APIs where the types aren't static-typed, there is an option to include type metadata

Now, I think some of that addresses some of your points. If you can fully specify a scenario that is problematic I might be able to be more specific (or think of new ways of torturing the code to make it work).

But to answer the headline question (non-decorated): yes, in v2

Comment: Thanks for anticipating this need!  I took the surrogate option for now, in that I decompiled the tiny framework classes and put them in my assembly.  Mostly I try to adhere to POCO, so a one-off like this isn't a big deal.  I'll check out new version 2 options.

Comment: @sgtz the SetSurrogate method should make that more direct and convenient

Comment: btw: I had a slightly older version of v2.  So, I hit update on svn, and now I can Serialize/Deserialize<Tuple<Data,Exception>>.  Also, I had to remove + readd the protobuf-net binary.  Not sure what that was about, but it is working nicely now.  Thanks for making this project public... and also, thanks to Google.  I should mention that at this point, I'm *still* using my copy of Tuple, not the one in the System namespace.